# haproxy config to route data and health checks onto different IP addresses

Tags: haproxy, cockroachdb

We have AWS S3 compatible object server configured to log S3 bucket notifications into CRDB (cockroach DB). S3 object server has the capability to configure CRDB endpoint. CRDB is live on distributed system setup - so I am trying to use haproxy as load balancer for CRDB servers.

Below is haproxy config. From my testing, I have noticed some times **S3 events are making to DB and other times they are missing**. When I use one of the cockroach DB server IP address directly in object server config and all S3 events are consistently able to make to DB. This isolated the problem on to haproxy load balancer.

Can any one advise (specifically the server line under  listen psql) to route data and health checks onto different IP addresses?

```
global
  maxconn 4096
  log 127.0.0.1 local0

defaults
    mode                tcp
    timeout connect     10s
    timeout client      1m
    timeout server      1m
    option              clitcpka

listen psql
    bind :26257
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk GET /health?ready=1
    server roach1 192.XX.XX.1:26257 check addr 172.XX.XX.1 port 8080
    server roach1 192.XX.XX.2:26257 check addr 172.XX.XX.2 port 8080
    server roach1 192.XX.XX.3:26257 check addr 172.XX.XX.3 port 8080
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dropping some of the requests sporadically"? And are you certain this is due to health checks? Do haproxy logs show the server failing health checks? btw: you have the same server in there three times.

Comment: @Marc, thanks for looking at my post. I have fixed the typo on three duplicate servers. I also updated the description with additional info.

Comment: It would be good to provide additional information about the client. Is this something you control? Be aware that most SQL drivers reuse connections. If a given connection is idle for 1m, haproxy will terminate it. You should adjust the client/server timeouts to match your application traffic.

Comment: @Marc, sure I will look into timeouts. Does the "server" under "listen psql" look ok specifically to route traffic onto different data and healthcheck end points?

Comment: It does. You should still check that health checks are successful though, it could be an issue with the nodes themselves. I believe haproxy logs health transitions, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. The health check are good - `curl -i http://192.XX.XX.11:8080/health?ready=1` returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` all the times.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for: ... check source <dest-ip> port <port>